# How do we use adverbs of frequency for something that should happen one time each ten years?

Tags: adverbs, time

DO we say "ten years once", for example? What's the correct form?

Comment: Do you mean **once in every ten year period**, or precisely **once every ten years on this date**?

Comment: Takes place every ten years.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **decennially** - e.g. *Our graduating class meets decennially*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decennial